# Facebook app alcohol resctriction

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im stuck with alcohol restriction on Facebook app. In developers zone I've set Content Restrictions to "Contains alcohol" and then in my app:

```
<?php 

$appTokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'
. 'client_id=' . $appId
. '&client_secret=' . $appSecret
. '&grant_type=client_credentials';

$appAccessToken = file_get_contents($appTokenUrl);  

$setUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. $appId . '?restrictions={"type":"alcohol"}'
. "&method=post&" . $appAccessToken;

$setResult = file_get_contents($setUrl);

echo '<pre>';
echo 'Set result: ' . $setResult . '<br />';
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Echo returns true. But if I use recommend plugin in this app, I still can recommend this app to underage Facebook users. Also underaged users can see the comments that come out of this app.

Any ideas how to make all app activity invisible for users who are underaged?

I would be appreciated for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you need to file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Im not sure this is bug. Because this issue was discussed earlier on facebook developers page - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/574/ (look at the post comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The like+send (recommend+send) buttons will be suppressed when the underage user visits an alcohol restricted app, so they will not be able to use the 'like', 'recommend', or 'send' buttons.

The comments plugin is visible as you said.  As a workaround, maybe you could display the comments plugin only for users who have auth'd your app.  That would prevent underage users from seeing the comments plugin because they cannot auth your alcohol-restricted app.

Comment: I guess app auth is the solution for this issue. Thanks.